# CSS method for inline links with icons?

Tags: css

I want to have a horizontal row of 3 links that use the same CSS style, but each link needs a small icon to the left, e.g | home | about | contact ...where | represents the icon.

I can get close using

```
.nav a {
    padding-left:8px;
    line-height:17px;
    background-image:url(/admin/img/icon.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    font-size:11px;
    height:17px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:block;
}
```

but this only works for one link and I have to display as "block", I need the same effect where the text is vertically aligned to the icon but keeping the link as an inline element so the varying widths are not an issue.

Comment: can you give your markup code here?So that we can help you as soon as possible.

Comment: I am not 100% of this, but line-height is not used since you used display block. (this is for information sake)

Comment: why do you "need" to use the display as block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `display:inline-block;` instead of `block`.